# Easiest way to define associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need an array like the following:

```
[0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2]
```

With this code:

```
var arr = [];

for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    arr[i] = i;
}
```

my array looks like this:

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

The values will then be updated by key like:

```
arr[0] = 2.5;
arr[1] = 8.4;
arr[2] = 3.7;
...
```

At the end, the arr will be sorted by value, so that I get for example the following order:

```
[[0:2.5],[2:3.7],[1:8.4],...]
```

Comment: See, `[0, 1, 2]` This is is equal to `{ 0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2 }`

Comment: you can use an object....

Comment: JavaScript does not have key => value arrays. You can use objects, or the ES6 `Map` object that is similar to a HashMap in Java

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: I want so sort my array later, so the order would change, but I still will be able to access them like `arr[1]`.

Comment: you can not sort an object

Comment: `arr[1]` will always give you the second element whether the array is sorted or not. Right now your keys are just indexes, so using an array should suffice. Can you provide a better example?

Comment: @FelixKling: Please see my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no notion in JavaScript of an associative array. There are objects, which are collections of key/value pairs. Objects are not ordered, so they cannot be sorted.

If you want to maintain order, I suggest using an array whose elements are themselves tuples containing index and value:

```
var array = [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]];
```

To update a value:

```
array[1][1] = 8.4;
```

You can sort by value with

```
var sorted_array = array.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])
```

Now you can get the value associated with "index" of `i` with

```
sorted_array.find(elt => elt[0] === i)[1]
```

This approach seems simpler than other suggestions which require maintaining two things, one an object giving the key/value pairs and another being an array giving a list of ordered keys.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't have the notion of an associative array.  You have to create an object.

```
var arr = {};
for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    arr[i] = i;
}
```

Comment: Can I still sort it like `obj.sort(sortFunc())`?

Comment: You can't sort an object, there isn't much point to doing that since you access values by key.  If you really need some kind of sorted access to an object, you would need to retrieve all the keys of that object into an array of keys, sort that array, then retrieve the object properties by iterating over the sorted key array.

Comment: But being able to sort is a requirement of the question.

Comment: Yes, but he can't sort an object.  So I've outlined a way where he can achieve what he wants by getting an array of keys, sorting the keys, then iterating over the array of keys to retrieve properties of the object.

Comment: Sure, but it's not an answer until you flesh that out.

Comment: You're right.  So the user should accept your answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array and objects for information like value and order.

The order is stored in the order property, the access of one element is still possible via the (usual array) index.

```js
function sort() {
    // get array and sort it and chnage order prop of objects
    array.map(function (a, i) { return { index: i, value: a.value }; }).sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.value - b.value;
    }).forEach(function (a, i) {
        array[a.index].order = i;
    });
}

function getSortedValues() {
    var r = [];
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        r[a.order] = a.value;
    });
    return r;
}


// build data structure
var array =  [2.5, 8.4, 3.7].map(function (a, i) {
    return { value: a, order: i };
});

sort();
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
// change a value
array[2].value = 9.9;
sort();
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getSortedValues(), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Then how do I sort it?

Comment: Yes, this is the right direction. But how we one assign a new value to an entry, as the OP wanted to do with `arr[1] = 8.4;`?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep two data structures around:

- An object that gives you `key => value` access.
- An array of `key`s that gives you order.

You could create a wrapper object that encapsulates those two and exposes an API to perform the desired operations (access by key, sort, iteration, etc).

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an Array of generic Objects ([working pen](http://codepen.io/sensei/pen/yOJZdE)) as it seems like you want to preserve each Array element's original index.  Basically you create the Array like so:

```
var arr = [];
var ARRAY_SIZE = 3;

for (var i=0, len = ARRAY_SIZE; i < len; ++i){
    arr[i] = { id : i, value : null };
}
```

write values like so:

```
arr[0].value = 2.5;
arr[1].value = 8.4;
arr[2].value = 3.7;
```

and then sort like so:

```
arr.sort(sort_function);
function sort_function (a, b)
{
  return a.value - b.value;
}
```

It's best to be explicit and name your properties - I chose "id" instead of 'original index' and "value" instead of an implied anonymous, but choose per its role in your application.